# How to bypass error 0xC0000225 when installing Windows Server 2016/2019/2022

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019, hardware-raid, windows-server-2022

When booting from a Windows Server install DVD or flash drive made with Rufus selecting MBR, I see error 0xC0000225 before being able to select the locale and keyboard type.
My BIOS is not capable of UEFI boot.

Specifics:

- Asus P6T6 motherboard with i7 940 CPU
- ICH10R onboard with an SSD attached in AHCI mode
- High-Point RocketRAID 3560 with a few SSDs attached

Comment: Same issue happens with Windows Setup UEFI boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing RocketRAID 3560 helped.  I was able to see Windows Server 2022 clean installation to the end.